# INSERT into database takes too much time

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, mariadb

I created an application and I tried to insert 100 records into my database (MariaDB) and it takes about 20s. How to speed up this operation?

I'm using hibernate and my expectation is inserting about 10k in max 2 min.

```
        private Person getPerson(ExternalPerson externalPerson) {
        Person person = new Person();

        person.setName(externalPerson.getFirstName());
        person.setLastName(externalPerson.getLastName());
        person.setAdditionalInfo(externalPerson.getIdentifier());
        person.setCountries(Arrays.asList(storeCountryIfNotExist(externalPerson.getCountry())));
        person.setGender(storeGenderIfNotExist(externalPerson.getGender()));

        personRepository.saveAndFlush(person);
        return person;
    }


    private Gender storeGenderIfNotExist(String gender) {
        Gender genderTemp = genderRepository.findByName(gender);
        if (genderTemp != null) {
            return genderRepository.findByName(gender);
        }
        Gender newGender = new Gender();
        newGender.setName(gender);
        return genderRepository.saveAndFlush(newGender);
    }

    private Country storeCountryIfNotExist(String country) {
        Country countrytemp = countryRepository.findByName(country);
        if (countrytemp != null) {
            return countrytemp;
        }
        Country newCountry = new Country();
        newCountry.setName(country);
        return countryRepository.saveAndFlush(newCountry);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly is going on... but if you are going to perform bulk operations, you would need to save and flush in the end I'd suppose. I am also not quite sure if writing to one table entails reads from another (in your case, that is...

Comment: Avoid flushing, don't load anything; let the database handle the duplicates.

Comment: What is `findByName` and why do you call it a second time, when have the result value?

Comment: Show us the resulting SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I can see that you are doing 3 inserts to create a record. That means, you are first inserting a country record using `storeCountryIfNotExist`, then a gender record using `storeGenderIfNotExist`, post these two, you are finally inserting `Person` record. This actually consists of 3 I/O operations as you are flushing everytime along with insert.

To improve your performance, you should try to minimize the count of your I/O operations. The first thing to do would be to flush only once after your 3 records are inserted. I haven't used MariaDB yet but like any other DB, instead of looping, MariaDB should be exposing a batch insert API which you can leverage to insert your 10K records in batches.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `someRepository.saveAndFlush(someEntity)` use `someRepository.save(someEntity)` and after you are done inserting all the records you can call `someRepository.flush()`.

`saveAndFlush` method goes to push your changes immediately after each individual inserts which increase DB round trips causing reduced performance.

Edit: Adding a sample code snippet.

```
for ( int i=0; i<10000; i++ ) {
    Person person = new Person(.....);
    session.save(person);

    if ( i % 50 == 0 ) { //50 is the batch size, which can be adjusted to find the sweet spot
        //instead of flushing after every save, flush batch of 50 updates together
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: how to know, when inserting is done and call .flush?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include example code snippet. So basically until you call flush, hibernate will keep your changes locally in memory. So depending upon your system resources and data you can adjust the value "50" to fine tune the performance. Let me know if you still have doubts.

Comment: thank you for you answer, I have a plan finish it today;)